# Reading xml row Objective C(IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xml-parsing

I have a xml like this:

```
<feed xmlns="xxxxxxxxxxxx" xml:lang="en-US">
<title>ServidorBaladasRSS</title>
    <Row Id="1" Name="Any" Contact="3849-6868" Gender="1" />
    <Row Id="2" Name="Any" Contact="3849-6868" Gender="2" />
    <Row Id="3" Name="Any" Contact="3849-6868" Gender="3" />
</feed>
```

I want to read every row and store in a object like :

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"])
{
    Object * object = [[Object alloc]init];
    object.ID = [attributeDict objectForId:@"Id"];

    [self.Rows addObject:object];
    [object release];
}
```

But it only stores the last value of the XML.
Any Idea?

Comment: Is that the entire xml?  Is there a parent node that contains the Row elements?  Where is Rows array created?  Put `NSLog(@"parserError = %@", [parser parserError]);` after calling the `parse` method.  What does it say?

Comment: I suggest you set some breakpoints and walk through your execution.  First make sure the parsing process behaves like you're imagining it to, and check the contents of your objects and containers at each step. After that, you might be able to edit your original question with some more clues about whats going on.

Comment: Sorry,edited the post with all the XML,i can acess the whole XML,if i log the  [attributeDict objectForId:@"Id"] i reads the correct numbers 1,2,3, but if i try to store it in a NSMutableDict,it only stores the last entry. @Anna Karenina the Rows is created in the same class,not in the function.